# UWP Custom Control Event Subscription Requires Wrong Type

Tags: c#, uwp, event-handling, custom-controls

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551026/uwp-textbox-cursor-functionality-on-down-key) and liked the answer. I created an event handler to implement that solution, but I didn't want to have to subscribe to that event on every single use of the TextBox. My solution was to make a custom control that subscribes to the event in the constructor, so that functionality will be the default. This worked, but it broke some other things.

I changed my other event handlers (text validation in the entries) to use the parameters `(TextBox_Custom sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs e)`. When I converted my 'TextBox's to 'TextBox_Custom's, these subscriptions gave errors. Even though I'm using a TextBox_Custom, the sender field of the BeforeTextChanging event is a TextBox. Is there any way to make it so the sender field is the actual control type instead of the inherited type?

This question touched on the same concept but didn't help me answer the question.
[UWP Template Control with Event Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624004/uwp-template-control-with-event-handler)

My solution was to create an overload that converts the sender, but this feels hacky and not best practice. See below.

EventHandlers:

```
    // This needs to be assigned in the constructor of the codebehind when used
    public static void IntValidation(TextBox_Custom sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        string current_text = sender.Text;
        string proposed_text = e.NewText;

        bool is_int = int.TryParse(proposed_text, out int n);

        if (!is_int && proposed_text != "")
            e.Cancel = true;
    }

    // TextBox_Custom triggers events with the sender being a TextBox still
    public static void IntValidation(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        IntValidation((TextBox_Custom)sender, e);
    }
```

Event Subscription:

```
    public Load_LogSelection()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Grs_weight_entry.BeforeTextChanging += Helpers.DoubleValidation;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<local:TextBox_Custom x:Name="Grs_weight_entry" Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Grs_weight, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="80"/>
```

Custom Control:

```
public partial class TextBox_Custom : TextBox
{
    public TextBox_Custom()
    {
        PreviewKeyDown += PreviewKeyDownEventHandler;
    }

    private void PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down)
        {
            if (sender is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox entry = (TextBox)sender;
                // Entry has text, nothing is selected and cursor is at index 0
                if (entry.Text.Length > 0 && entry.SelectionLength == 0 && entry.SelectionStart == 0)
                {
                    entry.SelectionStart = entry.Text.Length;
                    //entry.SelectionStart = entry.Text.Length -1;
                    entry.SelectionLength = 0;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though you are using `BeforeTextChanging` inside your custom textbox, but eventually `BeforeTextChanging` is an event of `TextBox` which is in your custom control, so according to this event signature it will take type `TextBox` as a first argument.

Comment: Hmm, is there a cleaner solution or is how I did it the 'correct' way to navigate this? It makes sense that the event signature doesn't change.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? Then, I could quickly understand what you've done and help you diagnose it.